# openssl command queries NGINX by ip and not hostname

Tags: curl, openssl, nginx, ssl

Here's a situation I am having a hard time understanding. I have nginx setup with two blocks for hosts like the following

```
server {
    server_name _;
    listen *:443 default_server deferred;
    return 444;
}
server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.ca;

}
```

The catch-all has a self-generated ssl certificate and the block to my application has a working SSL certificate. This setup is working for web browsers. If a web browser goes to `https://www.example.com` then they go to my application but if they go to `htpps://123.123.123.123` then it will just return nothing. But now I've run into a very weird situation. I was getting some requests to the domain that were failing (coming from a script) so I tried to debug. First I tried curling the url:

```
$ curl https://www.example.ca
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

I thought this was weird because the browsers all show the the certs as working as well as www.ssllabs.com shows that it's working. The next step I tried was viewing the SSL cert on the command line:

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.example.ca:443
```

This command actually shows my the SSL certificate for the catch all server block and not the `example.ca` block. If I add the ip address to the second nginx block then I see the ssl cert for `example.ca`. So now I know that openssl and curl are getting the wrong ssl cert because they are being served the wrong cert but I don't understand why?

I don't know much about openssl but all I can think of is either openssl/curl are wrongly converting the hostname to an ip address or they are forgetting to add a correct header? This is super strange and if anyone knows more I would appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vhost servers like nginx with multiple certs (and keys) use the Server Name Indication (SNI) extension to select the correct (vhost and) cert, but **by default `openssl s_client` does not send SNI** so you get the default cert; add `-servername $hostname` as described on the man page (right after `-connect`). There are lots of duplicates of this part on several other Stacks but I can't find one here. (UPDATE: OpenSSL 1.1.1 in 2018 fixed this; SNI is now the default unless you specify `-noservername`.)

OTOH `curl` does send SNI automatically (as do browsers and ssllabs) unless you have a really old version of either curl itself or the middleware it uses (which is *not* always OpenSSL; check `curl -V` uppercase). Try adding `-v` to get more details about what it's doing and getting, and if that's not enough get a wire trace with tcpdump/Wireshark/etc.